# wordpress - footer at bottom if screen is bigger than page

Tags: css, wordpress, footer

I have a wordpress site with Minamaze theme. It has some large pages and some small pages.

If the page is smaller than the screen, I want the footer to be placed at the bottom of the screen (and preferably vertical center the body).

If the page is larger than the screen, I want the footer to be placed at the bottom of the page (so visible after scroll down).

I have tried a lot of options like:

```
footer {
    position: relative;
    margin-top: -144px; /* negative value of footer height */
    height: 144px;
    clear: both;
}
```

and I see a lot about "wrapper", but none really work.

The site is http://www.samenherbestemmen.nl, hope someone can help.

**NB**: I have it now that the footer sticks to the bottom all the time, but I prefer the footer to be placed at the bottom of the page when the page is larger than the screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Codepen** http://codepen.io/noobskie/pen/wKpWXO?editors=110

I Think what your referring to is whats called a "sticky footer"

I used the same html markup with your current footer but i didn't use any of your css so you could run into some conflicts worth a shot though

**CSS**

```
* {
  margin: 0;
}
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}
.page-wrap {
  min-height: 100%;
  /* equal to footer height */
  margin-bottom: -142px; 
}
.page-wrap:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
}
.site-footer, .page-wrap:after {
  height: 142px; 
}
.site-footer {
  background: orange;
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
}
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}
.page-wrap {
  min-height: 100%;
  /* equal to footer height */
  margin-bottom: -142px;
}
.page-wrap:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
}
.site-footer,
.page-wrap:after {
  height: 142px;
}
.site-footer {
  background: orange;
}
```

```html
<div class="page-wrap">

  Content!

</div>

<footer class="site-footer">
  <div id="footer">
    <div id="footer-core" class="option4">
      <div id="footer-col1" class="widget-area one_fourth">
        <aside class="  widget widget_text">
          <div class="textwidget">
            <center><a href="http://www.grosfeldvandervelde.nl" target="_blank"><h3 class="widget-title"><font color="black">Grosfeld van der Velde</font><br><font color="#dbd8c1"> architecten</font>
</h3></a>
            </center>
          </div>
        </aside>
      </div>
      <div id="footer-col2" class="widget-area one_fourth">
        <aside class="  widget widget_text">
          <div class="textwidget">
            <center><a href="http://www.rho.nl" target="_blank"><h3 class="widget-title"><font color="black">Rho </font><br><font color="#dbd8c1">adviseurs voor leefruimte</font>
</h3></a>
            </center>
          </div>
        </aside>
      </div>
      <div id="footer-col3" class="widget-area one_fourth">
        <aside class="  widget widget_text">
          <div class="textwidget">
            <center><a href="http://www.pauwert.nl" target="_blank"><h3 class="widget-title"><font color="black">Van den Pauwert </font><br><font color="#dbd8c1">architecten</font>
</h3></a>
            </center>
          </div>
        </aside>
      </div>
      <div id="footer-col4" class="widget-area last one_fourth">
        <aside class="  widget widget_text">
          <div class="textwidget">
            <center><a href="http://www.verkerk-erfgoed.nl" tagert="_blank"><h3 class="widget-title"><font color="black">Verkerk </font><br><font color="#dbd8c1">erfgoed<font>
</font></font></h3></a>
            </center>
          </div><font color="#dbd8c1"><font>
  </font></font>
        </aside>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- #footer --><font color="#dbd8c1"><font>  
  <div id="sub-footer">
  <div id="sub-footer-core"> 

      <!-- #footer-menu -->

   <div class="copyright">
   Copyright <a href="http://www.bergtop-ict.nl">BergTop ICT</a>
   </div>
   <!-- .copyright -->

  </div>
  </div>
 </font></font>
</footer>
```

**edit** oops i forgot to mention you need to add the class `site-footer` to the parent `footer`

Comment: I have it sticky in the normal site, but in the mobile version, the height is also fixed, so I only se the first part of the footer. Any idea how I can make this only applicable for the normal site (not on the mobile site)??